# z-index not working properly over fixed element

Tags: html, css

I have a form (which toggles based on a button click) on top of the page:

```
<span id="add_toggle">+</span>
<form id="add_item">
    <!-- form stuff -->
</form>
```

I have list of items in a container, each items has the following structure:

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item_head">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item_body">
            contents of item 1
            <button class="btn">go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- similar items -->
</div>
```

`.item_body` initially has `dispaly: none;` and opens when `.item_head` clicked. It has a `position: fixed;` so all such elements show in the middle of the page.

Problem is when an `.item_body` is visible and the form opened, form goes below the item. I want it to be over.

I tried adding different `z-index` to `form`, `#items`, `.item` and `.item_body`. The only thing that works is when I give `.item_body` a negative `z-index`. But that makes it contents to be unreachable (e.g. button cannot be clicked, etc).

Here's a [**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/96Ly4b1y/1/).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z-index` property only applies to positioned elements (elements using a position other than the default of static). Add `position:relative` to your `<form id="add_item">`:

```
#add_item {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/96Ly4b1y/2/)**

Comment: OP 'is' using positioning. You're not telling anyone anything they don't already know.

Comment: @GaryHayes - The OP did not position the form element which is necessary when applying a z-index.

Comment: Yes, adding `position: relative` to the form fixed the problem, thanks.

Comment: @Samurai - Glad to help. I guess when GaryHayes said that I wasn't "telling anyone anything they didn't already know", I was telling him something he didn't know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hello there i had a look at you code **"Problem is when an .item_body is visible and the form opened, form goes below the item. I want it to be over"** the form is "over" the item.body and if you mean you want the form to not overlap the item.body you should check out the HTML structure since there is nothing there that separates properly these elements[screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1JIs.jpg)

Comment: Form goes over, because I gave `.item_body{z-index: -1;}` but as I said in the question, it made contents of `.item_body` unreachable. like the button cannot be clicked. This is just a demo to show the problem, the placements are fine though, form has more contents semi-transparent and so the item_body. @j08691 's answer solve the problem.